# python regex capturing array indicies and brackets

Tags: python, regex

this issue has me scratching my head. I have not yet been able to construct a regex which returns the captured groups I require. I've also been working with Pythex, and experimentation has not yet been successful.

Example source string: `'token[0][1]'`

I'm interested in a regex which will capture each of the array offsets, including the square brackets in separate groups. e.g. `g1 = '[0]', g2 = '[1]'`, for example.

The closest I can get is something like this:

```
r'(\[[\w]\])*'
```

Of course, this does not work. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `r'(\[\d+\])'` should capture what you want, like this:

```
import re

s = 'token[0][1]'

g1, g2 = re.findall(r'(\[\d+\])', s)

print g1, g2
[0] [1]
```